# Ionic Framework in Visual Studio Debug Device Error

Tags: android, visual-studio, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with IONIC Framework.

As the title, the IDE that I using is: Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition.

I create a little app (3 pages), with in only images. 
Now I need to test it on device, but I have compilation problems

The error is:

> Unable to deploy to Android device, no attached device was found. If you recently attached a device, you may need to wait a few seconds before it is recognized.

The question is, why? And how do I fix it?

However, I also installed the Google USB Driver in program SDK Manager (and Samsung USB Driver, because my device is a Samsung S5 Neo).

Comment: Is your device in USB debug mode?

Comment: Thx, this is a problem, i think that Debug USB is the same of "Unknown sources". This is because the developer mode was hide XD
Thx for all